# how inject bean in javax validation ConstraintValidator without spring

Tags: java, validation

I use javax validation. and I don't use springframework.
I wrote my specific annotation and specific ConstraintValidator

```
public class MyConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Myconstraints, String> {
  @Override
  public void initialize(...){
  ...
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    System.out.println("value=" + value + ", context=" + context);
    return false;
  }
}
```

and i need to use some outer 'service' for checking value in 'isValid' method.
Could I do it without springframework DI ?

I would like get something like this:

```
  ...
  MyService service;       

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
     System.out.println("value=" + value + ", context=" + context);
     if (service.check(value)) {
       return true;
     } else {
       return false; 
     }
  }
```

Comment: This question has changed 5 times since I first saw it and now has nothing to do with the constraint validation framework and is just about DI. Do some due diligence in the future before posting please.

Answer (score 0):

My solution (thanks the post https://marcin-chwedczuk.github.io/hello-hibernate-validator for an idea ):

```
class MyService {
    public String getProp(){
        return "something";
    }
}

class MyConstraintValidatorFactory implements ConstraintValidatorFactory {

    private MyService service;

    public MyConstraintValidatorFactory(MyService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public <T extends ConstraintValidator<?, ?>> T getInstance(Class<T> key) {
        if (MyConstraintValidator.class.equals(key)) {
            MyConstraintValidator validator = new MyConstraintValidator(this.service);
            return (T) validator;
        }

        if (key.getPackage().getName().startsWith("javax.validation") ||
                key.getPackage().getName().startsWith("org.hibernate.validator"))
        {
            try {
                return key.newInstance();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseInstance(ConstraintValidator<?, ?> instance) {
    }
}
```